# Compiling python3.4 for use with valgrind. What is still necessary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, valgrind

Looking at existing stackoverflow answers, there are 4 things recommended for using valgrind to debug python memory leaks.

`./configure` using:

- `--with-pydebug`
- `--without-pymalloc`
- `--with-valgrind`

It is also recommended on SO and in [README.valgrind](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/README.valgrind) to use a suppression file to suppress some valgrind errors.

I'm wondering:

1. Does the newer `--with-valgrind` option eliminate the need for this suppression file?
2. Does the `--with-valgrind` option eliminate the need for the `--without-pymalloc`?

Answers I've read:

- [use 3 options to ./configure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20126802/3022310)
- [use suppression file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037350/3022310)
- [--with-valgrind option is new](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7856043/3022310)