# Compilation of debug and valgrind -friendly version of Python

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, valgrind

I am a bit confused. I need to run Valgrind on a Python script that invokes some user-defined C/C++ routines which have critical memory leaks. With this aim, it seems that I need to have a debug+Valgrind friendly version of Python (2.7) as pointed [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/distnumpy/wikis/valgrind.wiki) and [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112989/how-to-use-valgrind-with-python).

The `python2.7` version that I have on my `Fedora 20` machine was originally installed by `yum` and, afaik is not a debug version. How can I get a debug version of python? Could I safely recompile my current python version (without the need to reinstall all the pacakges that I currently have)? Or should I compile a brand new `python2.7` version as detailed [here](http://pythonextensionpatterns.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging/debug_python.html)? In this latter case how can I make sure that upon calling of Valgrind, this debug version of python and not my currently existent version is chosen?

As I am prone to create damage when it comes to playing with installations, and I have no time for technical issues, I would like to have just one python version that can be used both with and without Valgrind, both in debug and non-debug (assuming that the debug version is equivalent to the standard one, i.e. w/out overhead). Unfortunately the link at the [bottom of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982036/how-can-i-use-valgrind-with-python-c-extensions/6037350#6037350) is broken.

Comment: According to https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/DebugPythonStacks you should be able to install a `python-debug` package with yum. You'd then  run it by typing `python-debug`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I would install it right away, but how can I verify that the debug package has been built `--without-pymalloc` option?